# React + AccuWeather location

Tags: reactjs, weather

AccuWeather says i need to make request to some city, then make another request for the weather based on the 'location key' which i obtained from the first request of that city. Issue is that IDK how to include the 'location Key' parameter in the weather request. For example 'location key' for Seoul is 226081 and for Busan 222888 from the API.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState('');

// GET "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/${226081}?apikey=${0G1vgC0oQj18gUyXgyjffHPGMVcf6}"

const url =`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=${0G1vgC0oQj18gUyXgyjffHPGMVcf}&q=${location}&language=en-us&details=true`;

const search_location = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data[0].Key);
    console.log(response.data);
    setData(response.data);
    console.log(data);
    return data[0];
  })
  setLocation('');
}
    
const weather_url = `http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/${weather}?apikey=${0G1vgC0oQj18gUyXgyjffHPGMV}&metric=true`;

  const search_weather = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch(weather_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="div">
      <form onSubmit={search_weather}>
      <h1>Search for weather</h1>
      <input
      value={weather}
      onChange={event => setWeather(event.target.value)}
      type="text"
      name="title"
      id="title" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" className='submit-button' />
    </form>


      <form onSubmit={search_location}>
      <h1>Search for a city</h1>
      <input
      value={location}
      onChange={event => setLocation(event.target.value)}
      type="text"
      name="title"
      id="title" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" className='submit-button' />
    </form>
    <div>
    <ul>
  {data.map(city => {
    return (
      <li key={city.Key}>
        <h3>City: {city.EnglishName}</h3>
        <p>Country: {city.Country.EnglishName}</p>
        <p>Administrative area: {city.AdministrativeArea.EnglishName}</p>
        <p>Timezone code: {city.TimeZone.Code}</p>
        <p>GMT Offset: {city.TimeZone.GmtOffset}</p>
        <p>Latitude: {city.GeoPosition.Latitude}</p>
        <p>Longitude: {city.GeoPosition.Longitude}</p>
      </li>
    )
  })}
</ul>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

JSON: Key: 226081

```
0:
AdministrativeArea: {ID: '11', LocalizedName: 'Seoul', EnglishName: 'Seoul', Level: 1, LocalizedType: 'Special City', …}
Country: {ID: 'KR', LocalizedName: 'South Korea', EnglishName: 'South Korea'}
DataSets: (12) ['AirQuality', 'AirQuality-Regional', 'AirQualityCurrentConditions', 'AirQualityForecasts', 'Alerts', 'DailyLocalIndices', 'ForecastConfidence', 'FutureRadar', 'HourlyLocalIndices', 'MinuteCast', 'PremiumAirQuality', 'Radar']
Details: {Key: '226081', StationCode: 'RKSF', StationGmtOffset: 9, BandMap: 'KOREA', Climo: 'RKSL', …}
EnglishName: "Seoul"
GeoPosition: {Latitude: 37.537, Longitude: 126.97, Elevation: {…}}
IsAlias: false
Key: "226081"
LocalizedName: "Seoul"
PrimaryPostalCode: ""
Rank: 10
Region: {ID: 'ASI', LocalizedName: 'Asia', EnglishName: 'Asia'}
SupplementalAdminAreas: []
TimeZone: {Code: 'KST', Name: 'Asia/Seoul', GmtOffset: 9, IsDaylightSaving: false, NextOffsetChange: null}
Type: "City"
Version: 1
```

below is what i'm getting back:

GET http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/seoul?apikey=0G1vgC0oQj18gUyXgyjffHPGMVcf&metric=true 400 (Bad Request)

{Code: '400', Message: 'LocationKey is invalid: seoul', Reference: '/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/seoul.json?metric=true&apikey=95df38db964c4236936b1e894a2f'}

Comment: Are you just asking how to dynamically add a value into a string in JavaScript?  It looks like you're already trying to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string interpolation.  But many of the values you're trying to use aren't defined anywhere in this code.  For example, `WEATHER_URL` (which you never use) is looking for a variable called `INCLUDE_CITY_KEY_HERE`, which isn't defined anywhere.  (It's also looking for a variable called `API_KEY` which isn't defined anywhere.)

Comment: Sorry about that, i edited the code to look exactly same as in my text editor. When i harcode the Key '226081' which is for Seoul. i get the results only for Seoul, but when i want to add ${weather} dynamically to weather_url it returns 400 LocationKey is invalid.

Comment: When you use `${weather}` then what is the value for `weather` at that time?  Did what you enter into the "Search for weather" input get successfully stored in the `weather` state variable?

Comment: I updated my question and included errors. For example i'm typing London, Seoul, Helsinki and it returns:... GET http://dataservice.accuweather.com/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/seoul?apikey=0G1vgC0oQj18gUyXgyjffHPGMVcf67cS&metric=true 400 (Bad Request) {Code: '400', Message: 'LocationKey is invalid: seoul', Reference: '/forecasts/v1/daily/1day/seoul.json?metric=true&apikey=95df38db964c4236936b1e894ad2232f'}

Comment: *"For example i'm typing London, Seoul, Helsinki"* - According to your previous information, the API is expecting values like `"226801"`, **not** values like `"Seoul"`.  Did you instead mean to use a value from your `data` variable instead of `weather`?  Why do you have *two* inputs for entering a city name?

Comment: I tried what you said and it works when i input 226081, 328328, 133328, but not when i input Seoul, London, Helsinki etc. which is a very weird thing, In the lower input i search for a city which then returns the 'location key' from API. In the 'Search weather' input i'm using the 'location key' to get weather information from that particular city. 'search weather' does not work with London but works with 328328 'location key from the API'

Comment: Both of the form submit operations use the value entered into their text input.  The result from the location search isn’t being used in the weather search.  It’s being stored in the “data” state value, but never used.  Maybe you meant to use “data” in the weather search?  Again, note that you have *two* text inputs.  If the intent is to use the result from the first operation as the input to the second operation then you should need only one text input.